# How do I alter an article on Wikipedia?

Tags: wiki, wikipedia

I would like to alter an article on Wikipedia how do I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is **click the Edit button at the top of an article's page**. In the page that you see afterward, you can make your changes and then save them.

---

You won't be able to edit some Wikipedia articles, however - instead of an Edit button, such **protected articles** will show a View Source button.

Also, when editing an article, it is recommended that you **click `Preview`** before you save your changes. This way, you can make sure that your changes were made as you intended.

For editing, you don't even have to log in. However, if you don't log in, there are a few disadvantages:

- Your IP address is posted and visible to the whole world - can lead to security issues
- You may lose some credibility

Before editing, I recommend you **read [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_welcome) [of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aFAQ) [Wikipedia's guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aTutorial)**, so that you understand how Wikipedia works and how articles are supposed to be.

One last thing - it may be hard to get used to **how formatting works** on Wikipedia. That's why they wrote a [cheatsheet for editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCheatsheet).

Answer (score 4):

To edit a page in Wikipedia:

1. Visit the page you would like to edit
2. An Edit link appears just above each section; click the Edit link above the text to change
3. Edit the text
4. Click the Save button to record your changes

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the relevant article, then click on "Edit" near the top right, make the changes you want, add a summary and click Save Page. The [Cheatsheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCheatsheet) could well be of use when you're doing this.